# Lifecycle ngDestroy in Angular 9 with ngIf and ngContent

Tags: angular

I implemented some basic stepper (tabs) and used *ngIf for hiding, not active tab content. But if I use the component in inactive tabs when the page was loaded component calls onInit(and not call onDestroy on leave) even if I not switching to this tab.

Attaching stackblitz to reproduce - [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hzn2vw). What am I missing?

AR: ngOnInit calls even if the second tab wasn't activated. And ngOnDestroy should not call on leaving this tab.

ER: ngOnInit not calls when first tabs rendered. And ngOnDestroy should call on leaving this tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. If you look at your template from your `AppComponent`:

```
<stepper>
  <step>
    some data
  </step>
  <step>
    <app-test></app-test>
  </step>
</stepper>
```

You clearly see the `<step>` and `<app-test>` both be there. There is no `*ngIf` logic wrapped around them, so they will always be 'initialized'. Not necessarily displayed, but the component instances do exist, because they are defined in the parent template, not in the `ng-content`. The `<ng-content>` is basically just a tag from which you can move an element from a parent component to a child component. However the context of the component stays in the parent, and the displaying of it should somehow be controlled by the parent.

There is a way to fix this. One way is to make your `StepComponent` a structural directive.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[step]'
})
export class StepDirective {
  active?: boolean;

  constructor(readonly tr: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
```

This changes your template to:

```
<stepper>
  <ng-container *step>
    some data
  </ng-container>
  
  <app-test *step></app-test>
</stepper>
```

Now the two steps are part of templates, and won't be initialized until you explicitly tell it to do so. For this we need to update the `stepper.component.ts`.:

<sub>(only showing the necessary updates)</sub>

```
@ContentChildren(StepDirective)
tabs: QueryList<StepDirective>;
```

Now all that's left is to use the `*ngTemplateOutlet` directive inside your `stepper.component.html`:

```
<div class="tab-body">
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="selectedTab.tr"></ng-template>
</div>
```

This controls the initialization of the templates and changes to what tab is active at the moment.

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7wygdl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper%2Fstepper.component.html)